# How to dynamically insert a value in a Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a project where users can create a company. However, there is a Theme that needs to be dynamically inserted, once the user chooses a theme on the frontend - more like when you want to choose a template in a no-code builder. Below is my models.py

```
class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/themes_images', null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, null=True)

class Company (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

For the Theme model, it is only the administrator who will create it and the user will only have to choose it on the front end. Sort of like when choosing a premade template in Weebly. All the Theme Objects will have their own page where the user can visually see which theme to go with:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def theme(request):
    themes = Theme.objects.all()
    context = {'themes': themes}
    return render(request, 'themes.html', context)
```

I haven't done much with the view, cause I am not sure how to go about it to achieve the desired result.

Themes.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% block 'title' %} <title>Themes | Simpledocs</title> {% endblock %}
{% block content2 %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2 class="my-4">Choose your theme</h2>
 <div class="columns">

  {% for t in themes %}

   <div class="column is-4">
    {{t.name}}<br>
     <img src = "/{{t.image}}" height="150px" width="150"/><be>
    {{t.category}}<br>
 
     <a class="button" href="#">Choose Theme</a>
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

So with a click on the above view, the user should be able to select a theme and apply it dynamically in the Company model on the theme entry. I have never dealt with such a challenge and need help here.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easy. Got the solution.

Create another view that shows individual themes:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block 'title' %} <title>Themes | Simpledocs</title> {% endblock %}
{% block content2 %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2 class="my-4">Choose your theme</h2>
<div class="columns">

 {{single_theme.name}}<br><br>
 <img src="/{{single_theme.image}}" /><br><be>
 {{single_theme.category}}<br>

 <form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
  <button class="button">Choose Theme</button>
 </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Create another View showcasing the theme. And execute the change of the Company.theme entry.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def theme_single(request, pk):
    single_theme = Theme.objects.get(id=pk)
    company = Company.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    for c in company:
        c.theme = single_theme
        c.save()
  
    return redirect('company')

context = {'single_theme':single_theme}

return render(request, 'theme_single.html', context)
```

This will change the company.theme model entry to the current theme selected.